# Modify eqnarray to match that of amsmath's align

Tags: equations, amsmath, align

This is a follow-up question to [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764).

Sadly, some journals (and their accompanying document classes) still require the use of `eqnarray` to arrange a number of equations in a single block. What would be the easiest (and best) way to modify the `eqnarray` environment to match the output of `align` *without* having to modify the input regime. Something that produces the *output* of the second set of equations (in `align`) given the first set (in `eqnarray`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
  f(x) & = & ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) & = & dx^2 + ex + f
\end{eqnarray}

\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{align}
  f(x) & = ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) & = dx^2 + ex + f
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to provide a very minimal package that could be added to a document when it still uses `eqnarray`, without having to modify the code used for `eqnarray`.

My first attempt was to modify the setup within `\eqnarray` (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)). Currently defined as

```
\def\eqnarray{%
   \stepcounter{equation}%
   \def\@currentlabel{\p@equation\theequation}%
   \global\@eqnswtrue
   \m@th
   \global\@eqcnt\z@
   \tabskip\@centering
   \let\\\@eqncr
   $$\everycr{}\halign to\displaywidth\bgroup
       \hskip\@centering$\displaystyle\tabskip\z@skip{##}$\@eqnsel
      &\global\@eqcnt\@ne\hskip \tw@\arraycolsep \hfil${##}$\hfil
      &\global\@eqcnt\tw@ \hskip \tw@\arraycolsep
         $\displaystyle{##}$\hfil\tabskip\@centering
      &\global\@eqcnt\thr@@ \hb@xt@\z@\bgroup\hss##\egroup
         \tabskip\z@skip
      \cr
}
```

It's obvious that the three components of an equation are handled *separately*. Additionally, a horizontal skip of `2\arraycolsep` is inserted around the middle component while also making that component equivalent to `\mathord` (wrapping it within `{..}`). A possible correction of this is therefore:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\makeatletter
\def\eqnarray{%
   \stepcounter{equation}%
   \def\@currentlabel{\p@equation\theequation}%
   \global\@eqnswtrue
   \m@th
   \global\@eqcnt\z@
   \tabskip\@centering
   \let\\\@eqncr
   $$\everycr{}\halign to\displaywidth\bgroup
       \hskip\@centering$\displaystyle\tabskip\z@skip{##}$\@eqnsel
      &\global\@eqcnt\@ne${}##{}$% Removed horizontal skip + forced mathord
      &\global\@eqcnt\tw@% Removed horizontal skip
         $\displaystyle{##}$\hfil\tabskip\@centering
      &\global\@eqcnt\thr@@ \hb@xt@\z@\bgroup\hss##\egroup
         \tabskip\z@skip
      \cr
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
  f(x) & = & ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) & = & dx^2 + ex + f
\end{eqnarray}

\setcounter{equation}{0}
\begin{align}
  f(x) & = ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) & = dx^2 + ex + f
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

What else?

Comment: What else? Automatic offset if the alignment is too near the equation number, for instance.

Comment: implement the code that supports `\qedhere`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: `\qedhere` is something that is not specific to `eqnarray` to begin with. So users of `eqnarray` would most likely not use `\qedhere`. The idea is that code `eqnarray` input code remains unchanged, while the output is updated to be better (like that of `align` + friends).

Comment: @Werner -- agreed, but if someone wrote a proof of a theorem that ended with a math display, then the `\qedhere` facility would be wanted (at least by a careful editor).  however, i *think* that no *math* journal requires `eqnarray` via its document class, and physicists and computer scientists don't usually deal in theorems and proofs, so maybe the point is moot.  (if you are certain that no *math* journal is a culprit, then i'll be happy to remove the comment.)

Comment: is loading the `amsmath` package allowed?

Comment: @jfbu: I would say "no," since users would then just use `align` from the start. However, a solution that uses [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) but maintains the input of `eqnarray` in all aspects would be okay I guess.

Comment: @Werner The most prominent error in the implementation of `eqnarray` is the spacing around the relation sign that makes the spot of the alignment. Also the syntax is awkward, but that's not changeable. You lose, as I said before, automatic offset when the display is too near to the equation number. Add `\displaystyle` also in the middle column, to avoid problems when that column is not really used for a relation.

Comment: How about the interesting `\label` feature in `eqnarray*`? See the example in my `eqnarray` article in PracTeX

Comment: @Werner my solution seems to at least do the job of correctly changing `eqnarray` to `align`. So the question might be now: Is it allowed to steal long pieces of code from `amsmath` (namely all needed by `align`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a robust solution based only on making `&` active. The code is well commented I hope:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\begingroup % we group everything so that our \catcode changes are local, and we use \gdef everywhere
\makeatletter
\gdef\eqna@origamp{&} % `&` stored
\catcode`\&\active % set `&` active in the scope of these hooks
\gdef\eqna@newamp{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\eqna@currenvir % if the inner-most environment is `eqnarray`
    \eqna@onlyfirstamp\let\eqna@onlyfirstamp\@empty % use `&`, but only once for each line
  \else % if there's another environment inside `eqnarray`
    \eqna@origamp % use `&` as is
  \fi
}
\gdef\eqna@hook{% modification of `eqnarray`
  \let\eqna@currenvir\@currenvir % store the current environment, which is `eqnarray` or `eqnarray*`
  \catcode`\&\active % `&` has to be active
  \let&\eqna@newamp % define `&` expansion
  \let\eqna@onlyfirstamp\eqna@origamp % `&` that is used only once on a line
  }
\catcode`\*11 % set `*` letter so that we can redefine `eqnarray*`
\gdef\eqnarray{\eqna@hook\align} % `eqnarray` is our hooks and `align`
\gdef\eqnarray*{\eqna@hook\align*} % `eqnarray*` is our hooks and `align*`
\global\let\endeqnarray\endalign
\global\let\endeqnarray*\endalign*
\endgroup

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{eqnarray}
  f(x) & = & \begin{cases} 1 & x\geq0 \\ 0 & x<0 \end{cases}\\
  \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} & = & dx^2 + ex + f \nonumber\\
  kkk(x) & = & gx^2 + kx + m
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{align}
  f(x) & = \begin{cases} 1 & x\geq0 \\ 0 & x<0 \end{cases}\\
  \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} & = dx^2 + ex + f \notag\\
  kkk(x) & = gx^2 + kx + m
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't forget about `eqnarray*`. However this requires `amsmath`, which probably is not allowed if the journal admits only `eqnarray`.

Comment: @egreg `*` done. And you are right that it requires `amsmath`. However, it at least does the job of converting `eqnarray` truly into `align`.

Answer (score 4):

> Transmutation of eqnarray into align

original enthusiasm: *I just didn't believe it when I saw it worked. Well it works in this very minimal case, but will certainly break I guess in real life*.

When I proposed the method I had hesitated between a an `active &` approach (exactly what `tochecz`'s code seems to do very robustly) and a more down-to-earth approach using delimited arguments. I was very surprised that I got the delimited argument method to work quickly so I posted it here and then extended to multi-line situations. I also wasted some time on extending to many-tabs as I didn't know that `eqnarray` was a strictly three column format with two tabs.

However if one wanted to extend the code to allow `\begin{env}...\end{env}` that would require quite an effort. Actually possibly recreating the amsmath `\collect@body` or similar (perhaps one could  just coerce it to serve us here). That's my two pence thought at this stage as I was busy with other things in-between and I come back to see that `tochecz` has implemented the idea of transmutation with the `active &` technique, obviously the much better choice. So purely by sentimentalism I will leave here some of my initial code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

\newtoks\arraytoaligntoks

%% Initial version for two lines
%%\long\def\eqnarray #1&#2&#3\\#4&#5&#6\end{%
%%    \arraytoaligntoks={#1&#2#3\\#4&#5#6}%
%%    \edef\endeqnarray{\noexpand\begin{align}\the\arraytoaligntoks
%%                     \noexpand\end{align}}\end}

%% version for arbitrarily many lines*
%% But this will fail completely if some \begin..\end is not within braces


\def\transmute #1&#2&#3\\{\arraytoaligntoks\expandafter
                     {\the\arraytoaligntoks #1&#2#3}}

\def\jfbu{\jfbu}

\long\def\eqnarray #1\end{\arraytoaligntoks{}%
    \def\\##1\\{\transmute ##1\\%
                \def\\####1\\{\ifx\jfbu####1\jfbu\else
                \arraytoaligntoks\expandafter{\the\arraytoaligntoks \\}%
                \transmute ####1\\\expandafter\\\fi}\\}%
    \\#1\\\\%
    \edef\endeqnarray{\noexpand\begin{align}\the\arraytoaligntoks
                      \noexpand\end{align}}\end}



\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{eqnarray}
  f(x) & = & ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) & = & dx^2 + ex + f \nonumber\\
  k(x) & = & gx^2 + kx + m
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{align}
  f(x) & = ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) & = dx^2 + ex + f \notag\\
  k(x) & = gx^2 + kx + m 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: with code verbatim]

Comment: This is specific to a two-liner `eqnarray` and "will certainly break I guess in real life".

Comment: The usage is similar to that of `align`, except for the fact the it requires a dual alignment character `&` as in my example. You can use it to set a single equation, two, or more, just like `align`. One would use `\nonumber` to remove a number in `eqnarray`, or use `eqnarray*` to remove all numbers (just like `align*`).

Comment: In retrospect, I'm glad to see that you may not have grown up with the `eqnarray` era in the sense that you didn't know if only took a double alignment `&`..`&` (and that's it)! :)