# Automatically replace environment align by equation+aligned combination

Tags: equations, environments, amsmath

I would like to automatically replace the align environment by an equation + aligned combination. Specifically, whenever `\begin{align}` occurs, it should automatically read it as `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}`. Similarly, `\end{align}` should be replaced by `\end{aligned}\end{equation}`. Occurrences of `\nonumber` also need to be gobbled up and ignored.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Any align such as
\begin{align}
x & = y + z, \nonumber \\
\alpha &= \beta + \gamma,
\end{align}
should automatically be replaced by an equation + aligned combination, effectively becoming
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x & = y + z, \\
\alpha &= \beta + \gamma.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Ideally, I would like to achieve this **without having to perform a manual replaceall throughout my document**. The simplest solution I see would be to create a new environment that achieves the required effects, but then I would still need to replace all existing uses of the align environment with the new environment.

I've not been able to find or create an implemention of this. The most related answer I've been able to find is: [Modify eqnarray to match amsmath align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96210/modify-eqnarray-to-match-that-of-amsmaths-align).

Comment: By help of TeX editor replace `\begin{align}` with `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}` and similarly `\end{align}` with `end{align}\end{equation}`. Editors are able to replace all occurrences of this replacing without any manual intervention.

Comment: @Zarko I would like to avoid using my TeX editor to achieve this. I'm looking for a method that I can apply to a complicated document structure, with several dozens of files, and, each file is actually part of different projects that preferably should not be changed. I would therefore like to avoid a hard replacement of \begin{align} and \end{align} in my source files. I'm instead looking for something along the lines of a redefined environment, or tying into environment hooks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `environ`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,environ}

\RenewEnviron{align}{%
  \let\nonumber\relax % this is local to this environment
  \let\notag\relax % this is local to this environment
  \let\tag\relaxtag % this is local to this environment
  \equation % start equation
  \!% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482
  \aligned % start aligned
  \BODY % the contents
  \endaligned % end aligned
  \endequation % end equation
}
\def\relaxtag#1#{\relaxrelaxtag}
\def\relaxrelaxtag#1{}

\begin{document}

Any align such as
\begin{align}
x & = y + z, \nonumber \\
\alpha &= \beta + \gamma,
\end{align}
should automatically be replaced by an equation + aligned 
combination, effectively becoming
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x & = y + z, \\
\alpha &= \beta + \gamma.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the `\!` you put before `\aligned` is there to cancel the `\null\,` in `\start@aligned`. Do you have any idea as why this small space is there in the first place?

Comment: @campa It has been discussed on the site, IIRC

Comment: [Found it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98482/why-is-there-a-space-at-the-beginning-of-the-aligned-environment), thanks.

Comment: I don't think the `\!` directive is needed if the objective is simply to replicate the look of a combined `equation`/`aligned` environment. For sure, with your code the first equation is shifted to the left -- by `\!` -- relative to the 'true' equation/aligned output shown at the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It defines a Lua function called `replace_align` that does the string replacements. `align` environments are replaced with `equation`/`aligned` combinations, and `align*` environments are replaced with `equation*`/`aligned` combinations.

The Lua function is assigned to the `process_input_buffer` callback, which operates at a very early stage on the contents of the tex file, *before* the TeX-side of LuaTeX does any real processing.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align", "aligned", and "equation*" environments

%% Lua-side code
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
in_align = false -- Set up a Boolean toggle variable 

function replace_align ( buff )
   if string.find ( buff , "\\begin{align" ) then
      buff = string.gsub ( buff , "\\begin{align(*?)}" ,
             "\\begin{equation".."%1".."}\\!\\begin{aligned}" )
      in_align = true     -- Set in_align to "true"
   elseif string.find ( buff , "\\end{align" ) then
      buff = string.gsub ( buff , "\\end{align(*?)}" ,
             "\\end{aligned}\\end{equation".."%1".."}" )
      in_align = false    -- Set in_align to "false"
   elseif in_align then  -- Gobble "\nonumber" and "\notag"
      buff = string.gsub ( buff , "\\nonumber" , "")
      buff = string.gsub ( buff , "\\notag" , "")
   end
   return ( buff )
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", replace_align, "replace_align" )
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}   
Any \verb+align+ environment, such as
\begin{align}
x      &= y + z,  \nonumber \\
\alpha &= \beta + \gamma,
\end{align}
should automatically be replaced by an \verb+equation/aligned+ combination, effectively becoming
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x      &= y + z, \\
\alpha &= \beta + \gamma.
\end{aligned}\end{equation}    
\end{document}
```